# Uniform Convergence of random variable on a compact set

Tags: probability, limits, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose $\{f_n\}_{n\in N} $ are functions defined on a compact set $K \subset R$ where each $f_n(k)$ is a random variable. 
Further suppose that there exist a continuous function $f:K\rightarrow R$ such that  $f_n(k)\rightarrow f(k)$ in probability. My question is:
$$sup_{k \in K}|f_n (k)-f(k)|\rightarrow 0 \ ~ \text{in probability?}$$
I don't even know whether it is true or not. Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: @DavidMitra Thanks for the comment! I think the example in the given link does not fit my question since $X_n(\omega)$ does not converge to any constant(and since $X_n(\omega)$ is a trivial random variable, convergence in probability and convergence are equivalent.)

Comment: Ooh, sorry; I didn't read your question carefully enough.

Comment: This is not true, just take your favorite example of a sequence converging pointwise but not uniformly to a continuous limit.